# Simplify the following proposition using the operator properties ( simplifiable or not ? )

Tags: logic

I tried to simplify the following proposition using the operator properties, but it is not working. Can i have some help please ? I am lost, line $2$.

$$\neg p \land [(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)] \equiv \neg p \land q \land r$$
$$(\neg p \land p) \lor (\neg p \land q) \land (p \lor r) \equiv \neg p \land q \land r$$

So : I eliminate the $()$ and $[]$, i do distributivity and now can we do something or it is impossible ?

I know that the priority follow this guideline: $()$ ; $\neg$ ;  $\land$ ; $\lor$ ; $\to$ ; $\leftrightarrow$.

Thanks, 
Anthony.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) on $(p∨q)∧(p∨r)$ to get $p∨(q∧r)$.

Comment: Thus, the LHS will be $¬p∧(p∨(q∧r))$. By Distributivity again we get: $((¬p∧p)∨(¬p∧q∧r)) ≡ F ∨ (¬p∧q∧r) ≡ (¬p∧q∧r)$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, i understand now ! thanks Mauro ! i wish i could be as good ! practice, practice.